# Introduction To C++ IO Streams

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, iostream

I got a snippet of code from [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-iostreams.html) and I'm confused as to how it works? The snippet starts by saying:

> You can detect that a particular read or write operation failed by testing the result of the read. For example, to check that a valid integer is read from the user, you can do this:

```
int x;
if ( cin >> x ) 
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid number" << endl;
}
```

> This works because the read operation returns a reference to the stream.

I understand that the cin >> x operation returns a reference to cin but I'm still confused as to how evaluating the reference to the standard input stream object allows you to check that the input is a valid integer.

Comment: That would be because of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Comment: I am not sure that code does what it claims... is the `if` condition negated? should it be?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yup, it should be. That's a mistake on the author of the article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cin` is an instance of `istream` template class. `operator >>` acts on this istream instance  to load input into data and returns a reference to this `istream`. Then in `while` condition it is tested by a call to `cin::operator void*() const` (`explicit operator bool() const` in C++11) which invokes `fail()` function to test if operation succeeded. This is why you can use this operation in while condition

```
while ( cin >> x)
{
   //...
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/ ), the operator

```
explicit operator std::ios::bool() const;
```

"Returns whether an error flag is set (either failbit or badbit)." and "The function returns false if at least one of these error flags is set, and true otherwise."

Thus when the `if` statement casts the `cin` stream to `bool`, this operator returns `false` if the stream has an error flag set, and `true` otherwise.

Comment: As pointed out by @David Rodríguez, the source article has the logic reversed.  You can double-check with the documentation and/or experiment for yourself!